# How to convert a list of strings to ints in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

When I read in a file

```
nums = sc.textfile("hdfs location/input.txt")
```

I get a list of strings.
If I use Scala in Spark, I can convert the data to ints by using

```
nums_convert = nums.map(_.toInt)
```

I'm not sure how to do the same using pyspark though.  All the examples I went through online work with a list of numbers generated in the script itself as opposed to loading a file.  Or the format of the file is something that would make sense to be in a dataframe (tab separated columns of data).

I tried using Python's map but it complains that nums is not iterable which makes sense.  Ultimately, I'm just trying to process a list of numbers from a file but not sure how to convert the strings to something I can actually use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not much difference here if you explicitly write out the lambda

In Scala

```
nums_convert = nums.map(x => x.toInt)
```

In Python

```
nums_convert = nums.map(lambda x: int(x))
```

Or, you can do it implicitly

```
nums_convert = nums.map(int)
```

> I tried using Python's map

RDD is not an iterable. It has its own map function. Also, thinking of an RDD as an actual "list object" will only result in more errors

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't thinking of it as a list but thought it might be like Scala where I can use a similar method to process the structure.  This works.  Thanks!

Comment: Well, Python and Scala's list object map functions are slightly different